# PHP script not inserting values into mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

my insert isnt working, It ownt insert anything into the DB no matter what.

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO 'users' (`id`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (NULL,   '$newusername', '$newpassword')";
```

What did i do wrong? :(
And yes i have connected to the DB earlier in the script.

Edit: Heres my whole .php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $newusername = $_POST['newusername'];
    $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
    $newpassword2 = $_POST['confirmnewpassword'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$newusername' AND password = '$newpassword'";
if(strlen($newusername) > 5 || strlen($newusername)< 25){
echo "username length check is fine<br>";
    if(strlen($newpassword) > 4 || strlen($newpassword2) < 25){
        echo "Pass check worked lel<br>";
        if($newpassword == $newpassword2 ){
            echo "Should all be working!<br>";
            $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Couldnt connect!");
            mysqli_select_db($connect,"phplogin") or die("Couldnt find DB.");

            $sql="INSERT INTO users (username,password) VALUES('$newusername','$newpassword')";


        }
        else
            die("Passwords did not match");
    }
    else
        die('Password wasnt long enough');
}
    else
        die("Username was not long enough");

}
```

Sorry for the messy code. i get a feeling ive left something very obvious out.

Comment: Is `id` a `PRIMARY KEY` ? Because if so you can't insert `NULL` values.

Comment: @Daan NULL is silently converted into auto_increment value (on MySQL).

Comment: is ID not auto increment? or allow null?

Comment: Try using backticks on the table name and not quotes

Comment: @MihaiStancu I wasn't asking for auto_increment.

Comment: The code you are showing just puts your query in a variable, it doesn't execute it. Are you doing that further down the line?

Comment: issue is with `id` single quote , use 'id'

Comment: Issue is due to single quote used with "`id`", "`username`", "`password`"

Comment: @Kasma MySQL uses single-quotes for values.

Comment: @MihaiStancu there is difference between Apostrophe and Grave accent, which is probable error in this query to execute in php

Comment: As stated below @Kasma, Grave accents are used to enclose column names. This is perfectly fine. Please review the mysql documentation.

Comment: Here is a sample: INSERT INTO l4stal13prema00.`fusion` ( `partition en` ,
`classe` ,
`segment` ,
`F tot` ,
`F loc` ,
`indice specif` )
SELECT *
FROM f3p1
WHERE 1;

Comment: Try doing `mysql_query($sql);` to actually execute the code.

Comment: Actually do `mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());` to get the output of the query if there is an error.

Comment: And you should probably consider switching to prepared mysqli or pdo statements, not deprecated mysql_* functions.

Comment: Show us the code that does the connecting part (remove the passwords and such). Show us the code that actually runs the query. Tell us if you're using mysql, mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @TaylorStevens you are not executing the  $sql statement , so I guess this creating the problem.

Comment: @TaylorSteve as @DeepakGoswami said... you're just building a string containing the sql query... you're not actually calling the `mysqli_query` function at all. Basically one of those "is your computer plugged in" type of problems.

Comment: @TaylorStevens Don't delete the contents of your questions after they are answere. StackOverflow uses this page to cater to you as well as future readers. Answered questions are a valuable resource to future readers with similar problems, that's why you'll find plenty of old StackOverflow answers on Google searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### At the PHP level:

In PHP you should make a habbit of setting up error levels to let you know when things become weird:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('scream.enabled', false);
```

With these settings you'll start seeing some PHP errors such as trying to access the contents of arrays that you expect to be populated by the DB but in fact are not (and they may not even be arrays). These are tip-offs to get you thinking that an SQL query has failed for some reason.

### At the DB level:

Most likely you database is telling you exactly what is going on, you're just not checking what it's saying. Errors from the database manifest themselves in 3 ways: empty results, false instead of expected result, an error message available to you if you check for it.

Check for errors after each step:

- connect to DB;
- select DB (in case you're using `mysql_*` or `mysqli_*` functions);
- prepare statement (in case you're using `mysqli_` or `PDO`);
- execute query;

I will assume you're using `mysqli_*` functions and give an example (original [here](http://php.net//manual/en/mysqli.error.php)):

```
/** somewhere in the DB connection file */
$mysqlErrors = array();

/*...*/

/** somewhere in your logic files */
$rows = mysqli_query($link, "SET a=1");
if ($rows === false) {
    $mysqlErrors[] = mysqli_error($link);
}

/*...*/

/** somewhere in your template files */
foreach ($mysqlErrors as $mysqlError) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqlError);
}
```

Comment: Ive already done that, everything is being printed fine, It shows the persons username / password they entered in the form and it echos out after the insert function

Comment: Yes, but what are you doing to check for errors during the insert function?

Comment: @TaylorStevens you are checking for PHP errors I am talking about DB errors. Each different mysql library (mysql, mysqli and PDO) has its own error checking function. That error checking function give you the information returned by the database.

Comment: @JustinE im not too sure i would go about catching a error during the insert function, For now im just using echo

Comment: @TaylorStevens check my example about how you catch mysql errors.

Comment: Set as answer for being well informative and nicely structured, Thank you.

Comment: @TaylorStevens Where is your: `mysqli_query($sql);`?

Answer (score 0):

```
(1) do this,  id as auto increment then no need to include at insert time 

$sql= "INSERT INTO 'users' ( `username`, `password`) VALUES ('$newusername', '$newpassword')";
```

Comment: @TaylorStevens just pushing harder with every possible variation on the same issue is not going to help you much. It's like trying to break a password by brute-force trying every one of them -- it might eventually work but it's not worth it.

Comment: @TaylorStevens stop trying every answer people offer and start rationalizing the issue behind the problem. Find out why your current stuff doesn't work, show the error messages you receive and after that if the error messages are not self-explanatory we will be able to assist with some real advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO 'users' ( `username`, `password`) VALUES ('$newusername', '$newpassword')";

// add the following code below the line above

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Answer (score -3):

Use Apostrophe instead of Grave accent
` = Grave accent, or (because someone needed to invent a word) backtick
' = Apostrophe, or straight single quote

```
(`id`, `username`, `password`)
```

You should use this

```
('id', 'username', 'password')
```

Comment: ` is typically used to show column names...so they did nothing wrong in that regard. Values should be enclosed in ticks.

Comment: @JustineE ,  you are correct , Grave accent will be affected only if it was used in values part.. +1 for correct information

Comment: Making this change is not correct and will cause the query in the question to throw a mysql error.